# Robot framework - How to go through X element while there are pages until element Y is found

Tags: robotframework, ui-automation, browser-automation, webautomation

I am recently new to Robot framework and I can't seem to find the answer to my exact problem anywhere.

**Context:** I need to go through all the titles on my page until I find a specific one determined by my global variable. The UI does not have unique ids so when I enter the title locator, I get 20 or more elements matching this XPath.

There is also pagination, meaning that the title I'm looking for might be on another page.

My global variable, which is the title I'm looking for, is `${audience_name_value}` and I get its value in another keyword. I think this bit is working since when this title is on the same page, the test passes with the keyword

`Page Should Contain Element    ${current_page['audience_name_card_holder_title']}${audience_name_value}")]`.

The problem is when the title I am looking for is placed on the second page or third, etc.

I wanted to iterate each title until the right one is found or click on the next arrow to continue this search.

---

At first, I was getting the error: `TypeError: Expected argument 1 to be a list or list-like, got string instead.`

```
the created audience is in the inactive custom audience section
   ${elements}=  Get WebElements                  xpath://*[@id="pageContainer"]//div[contains(@class,"audienceCard__header__name")]/a
    FOR    ${element}    IN    @{elements}
        ${text}=    Get Text    ${element}
        Exit For Loop If        ${text} == ${audience_name_value}
    END
```

So I tried to create a list below but now I keep getting this error:
`Evaluating expression 'RBT 2021-12-21 == RBT 2021-12-21' failed: SyntaxError: invalid syntax (<string>, line 1)`

```
the created audience is in the inactive custom audience section
    ${elements}=  Get WebElements                  xpath://*[@id="pageContainer"]//div[contains(@class,"audienceCard__header__name")]/a
    ${list}=    Create List    ${elements}
    FOR    ${element}    IN    @{list}
        ${text}=    Get Text    ${element}
        Exit For Loop If        ${text} == ${audience_name_value}
    END
```

I'm out of ideas, it seems like the title was found but there is a syntax error I just can't seem to fix.

I kindly ask for help :D, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Here in this code, you created a list but it still get string returned from the web elements. Better to use something like below:
First, capture full web page content in ${var} then use kw
Get lines containing string or Get Substring that you are looking for from that ${var}, use this with kw Run keyword If/IF loop.